# Is it possible to use the iPad mobile data for all WAN access on a Linksys router?

Tags: routing, home-networking, dd-wrt, ios, ipad

I have an iPad with unlimited data and the personal hotspot feature. I also have a Linksys WRT3200ACM running DD-WRT. This router is my primary router for my home network devices (NAS etc).

Would it be possible to use the iPad’s mobile data plan for all WAN access on a Linksys router?

I would like both my wired and Wi-Fi devices to have Internet through my iPad. Also, it would be ideal to have my other Wi-Fi devices to connect to my Linksys, due to the stronger signal.

Some ideas I have had:

- Buy a Thunderbolt > ethernet adapter, and plug this into the WAN port
  on the Linksys. Would the iPad automatically try to prioritize
  ethernet and search for an IP?
- Connect iPad to Linksys SSID, change Linksys default gateway to iPad,
  and then iPad gateway to 0.0.0.0?
- Completely remove the Linksys, build a Linux box/router, plug the iPad into the new PC via USB, and then somehow share the USB connection out to ethernet?

Does anyone know if there is any iOS limitations here? Any other possible solutions?

[image: Basic Network Layout]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set this up fine with [Client Mode](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Mode_Wireless).
Another option would've been iPhone tethering option. DD-WRT supports this on some models.